# How to transfer an XFB file using command BTOPUT in unix server

Tags: unix

We have one .sh file which contains all the configurations. 
We have something like this,
export MARK_REMOTE_NODE= (server name)

The requirement is we have to send the same file to two different servers.Is it possible to transfer the same XFB file to different REMOTE_NODE or servers in UNIX??

When i was searching i got to know that BTOPUT transfers are one file at a time to one Partner.So can anyone tell me how to transfer file to 2 different servers?

Answer (score 0):

XFB already has a hard job matching different operating- and filesystems with optional compression and retry mechanism. You want some logic what will happen when 1 transfer fails (only send second when first succeeds, shoot-and-forget, always try to send both and trust your incident management to catch the errors thrown by your monitoring, wait for async transfer for time depending on filesize,..).
I wouldn't trust the XFB options and just make a loop in your script doing exactly what you want. The additional advantage is that a migration to another communication tool will be easier.

```
while read -r targethost; do
   # You need a copy, since xfb will rename and delete the file
   cp outputfile outputfile.${targethost}
   my_send_xfb ${targethost} outputfile.${targethost}
   # optional check result posting the file in the queue
   if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
      echo "Xfb not ready or configured for ${targethost}"
      # Perhaps break / send alert / ..
   fi
done < myhosts
```